# How do I make a quick line border in my website?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a thin line border that goes across the width of the web page. The way I’m doing it right now is by putting a `<p>` tag in the `<div>` element because without anything inside my `<div>` nothing shows up and making the text the same color as the background.

But is there a more efficient way of making a line border without having to put a `<p>` tag inside my `<div>` element?

HTML:

```
<div class="lineborder">
  <p>line</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.lineborder {
  background-color: #4f5054;
}

.lineborder p{
  color: #4f5054;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `hr` tag. It will run across the web page.

Then you can style it like so:

```css
hr {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  height: 10px;
  /* More styles */
}
```